# Почему функция get_the_ID() возвращает пустой результат?

Tags: wordpress

В файле functions.php дочерней темы пишу

```
$get_page_ids = get_the_ID();
print_r ( $get_page_ids );
```

В итоге возвращается пустой результат. Если этот же код вывести в header.php или footer.php, то успешно отрабатывает.

Пробовал такой вариант (в functions.php):

```
function get_page_info() {
    echo get_the_ID();
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'get_page_info' );
```

Результат успешно выводится.

Пожалуйста, подскажите, почему не работает первый вариант в functions.php.

Comment: Каждый из вариантов работает ровно так, как должен. Первый вариант не возвращает ожидаемые вами данные потому, что в момент вызова функции `get_the_ID()` ещё не установлены переменные запроса

Comment: Спасибо. Подскажите еще, пожалуйста, на какой лучше хук вешать свою функцию, если в ней требуются вызовы функций типа get_the_ID() или get_page_uri() с последующими нужными редиректами после проверки этих данных? На хуке "init" значения тоже пустые.

Comment: В общем случае на хук `wp` (`add_action( 'wp', 'get_page_info' );`), он срабатывает сразу после установки глобальной переменной $wp.

Comment: А в целом рекомендую почитать что-нибудь вроде этого https://wp-kama.ru/hooks/actions-order

Comment: Благодарю Вас за помощь!